# Why i can't get to the events of the global keys hooking ?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a new form i tried before with a new class but the same problem.
I created a new form and added:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Capture
{
    public partial class Hook_Keys : Form
    {
        globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();
        public bool onoff = false;

        public Hook_Keys()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Hook_Keys_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.A);
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.B);
            gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
            gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
        }

        void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            onoff = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            onoff = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in another class at the top i did:

```
Hook_Keys hookeys = new Hook_Keys();
```

Then using it:

```
if (hookeys.onoff == true)
                            {
                                font.DrawText(null, String.Format("{0:N0} fps", this.FPS.GetFPS()), 5, 5, SharpDX.Color.Red);
                                string timeRunning = FramesPerSecond.RunTime.ToString();
                                font.DrawText(null, String.Format("{0:N0} time running ", timeRunning), 5, 30, SharpDX.Color.Red);
                            }
```

The problem is that it's never getting to the events gkh_KeyUp and gkh_KeyDown in the new form.

I also must say that the project i'm trying to use it now is a class library project type.

I tried to use it before on a simple windows forms application without any classes or new forms just windows forms application in form1 and it's working fine.

I took the source code from here:

[Global Keys Hooking](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

Comment: Note that the original code was from 2007 - it's perfectly possible there's some security measure preventing it from working as you intend. What are you actually trying to do? Why are you registering global keyboard hooks?

Comment: So you use the `Hook_Keys` form simply to contain the key hooking code and nothing else? Are you ever showing that form?